# After submitting an ajax-php contact form - open bootstrap modal for popup message

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to display this massage "Thank you!" via bootstrap modal instead of alert.

```
//AJAX code to submit form.
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
                            alert("Thank you!");
                                }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give your modal an `id` something like "*thankyouModal*", [ref creating modal](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-modals.php)

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
                            $("#thankyouModal").modal('show')
                                }
});
```